# xtrabackup - copying my.cnf file from source to replica when there are different linux distros on source and replica

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, xtrabackup

https://docs.percona.com/percona-xtrabackup/innovation-release/set-up-replication.html#3-configure-the-sources-mysql-server

```
4. Configure the Replica’s MySQL server
Copy the my.cnf file from the Source to the Replica:
$ scp user@Source:/etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf and change the following options in /etc/mysql/my.cnf:
server-id=2
```

My source is Almalinux 9, replica is Ubuntu. Copying the config file from source to replica will mess up the replica mysql.

How do we make it work?